# Handel Strange Application flow - Android

Tags: android, android-music-player

I got in to strange problem with the flow of application.I am creating music Playing application, which have capability of background playing. And the problem I am having is,

1. on application starts application loads all the songs from SD card.
2. User starts the playing of song.
3. Now he **exit** form the application.
4. songs is **still playing** in the background.
5. Now when he **starts application** again either from Notification bar or from the menu... all songs starts **loading again** Now that is the thing I don't want.

can any one suggest me how to handle this thing ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resume application and stack from notification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502427/resume-application-and-stack-from-notification)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your notification intent must be identical to the launcher intent.

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5502950/377478