# Start / Resume Task Back Stack from Notification as Recent Apps Switching

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, stack, resume

My application has two activities **A** and **B**. **A** is the root activity and set with **singleTop** launchMode. **B** is started from **A**, i.e. the task stack is (***A->B***)
I add a status notification to launch the application as long press Home button. The notification intent point to activity **A**.

When the task stack is (***A***) only, the intent invokes onNewIntent() from existing **A**, as expected.
When the task stack is (***A->B***), the intent create new activity **A**. But what I wants is resume task (***A->B***) as switch recent apps by long press Home button.

Is the problem caused by incorrect launch mode used? or any flags need to be added to the notification intent?

Thanks.

Comment: Read this post on how to handle launching activities from a notification: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resume application and stack from notification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502427/resume-application-and-stack-from-notification)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following from your notification manager:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActivityA.class);
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Make sure that your `ActivityA` is not launched with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`.