# Intent - if activity is running, bring it to front, else start a new one (from notification)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-pendingintent

My app has notifications, which - obviously - without any flags, start a new activity every time so I get multiple same activities running on top of each other, which is just wrong.

What I want it to do is to bring the activity specified in the notifications pending intent, to the front if it is already running, otherwise start it.

So far, the intent/pending intent for that notification I have is

```
private static PendingIntent prepareIntent(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);

    return PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
```

and weirdly, it sometimes works, sometimes it doesn't... I feel like I've already tried every single combination of flags.

Answer (score 140):

You can use this:

```
<activity 
   android:name=".YourActivity"
   android:launchMode="singleTask"/>
```

which will work similar to `"singleInstance"` but it won't have that weird animation.

Comment: +1, you should be the accepted answer. Differences are here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode

Comment: To clarify, use singleTask if you have multiple activities in the app and this is the parent, singleInstance if you have only one Activity.

Comment: If anybody like me has tried many combinations of solutions before they ended up on this site: Make sure to get rid of other changes you tried and make sure you do this change to the correct activity.

Took me far too long to find out that this solution would've worked if I hadn't tried other solutions as well (e.g. overriding `onNewIntent` and setting flags)

Comment: I have a map of Messenger, Activity pair. I want to display the Activity instance if I get a message from it. Is there any way of doing this. eg: HashMap.get(Messenger).bringActivityToFront(); I mean, the activity is still running. If I open recent task and click it, it will onResume(); Cant I onResume() programatically.

Comment: @JaveneCPPMcGowan that seems like a different question altogether, I suggest you post that as it's own question, I don't really know the answer unfortunately.

Comment: @Franco I lost my rights to post questions. Everything I ask gets downvoted. Everything I answer get downvoted. This is my only way to get information. Anyhow I found the answer. ActivityManager.moveTaskToFront(Activity.getTaskId(), flagValue); You also need to use android.permission.REORDER_TASKS.

Comment: Sorry to hear about that @JaveneCPPMcGowan, good that you found a solution for your problem though.

Answer (score 49):

I think the best way to do it and in a simple manner is to start the activity normally, but set that activity in the manifest with the `singleInstance` property. With this you practically approach both issues you are having right now, by bringing the activity to the front all the time, and letting the OS automatically create a new one if no activity exists or bring to the front the currently existing activity (thanks to the `singleInstance` property).

This is the way an activity is declared as a single instance:

```
<activity 
   android:name=".YourActivity"
   android:launchMode="singleInstance"/>
```

Also to avoid a choppy animation when launching through singleInstance, you could use instead "singleTask", both are very similar but the difference is explained here as per Google's documentation:

```
<activity 
   android:name=".YourActivity"
   android:launchMode="singleTask"/>
```

> singleInstance is the same as "singleTask", except that the system
>   doesn't launch any other activities into the task holding the
>   instance. The activity is always the single and only member of its
>   task.

Hope this helps.

Regards!

Comment: it seems to work, but now every other new activity I launch from the singleIntent MainActivity, play this weird arcing animation instead of the regular fade&scale

Comment: What about I launched a new activity every time but clear all other running instances of it, would that be possible?

Comment: Well, i don't think the animation you mention has anything to do with the "singleInstance" property, all it does is reusing existing instance, maybe that animation you are talking about is a complete different issue...

Comment: well I am testing it right now and it does. If I remove all the intent flags and just set the launchMode="singleInstance" in the manifest, the weird animation is there, if I remove it, its back to normal

Comment: Yes, according to android documentation, seems like the "init" animation is no longer there as usual because the activity is not being initialized, is just being reused...

Comment: but it happens when I launch the DetailActivity from MainActivity, which is weird, If I have MainActivity running and get notification and click it, then yes, theres no animation ("from" MainA to MainA)

Comment: Try calling this method after starting the activity: overridePendingTransition(0,0);

Answer (score 27):

I think what you need is in `singleTop` `Activity`, rather than a `singleTask` or `singleInstance`.

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
          android:launchMode="singleTop"
          ...the rest... >
```

What [the documentation says](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) does perfectly suit your needs:

> [...] a new instance of a "`singleTop`" activity may also be created to handle
>   a new intent. However, if the target task already has an existing
>   instance of the activity at the top of its stack, that instance will
>   receive the new intent (in an `onNewIntent()` call); a new instance is
>   not created. In other circumstances — for example, if an existing
>   instance of the "`singleTop`" activity is in the target task, but not at
>   the top of the stack, or if it's at the top of a stack, but not in the
>   target task — a new instance would be created and pushed on the stack.

On top of that (no pun intended), I had exactly the same need as you. I tested all the `launchMode` flags to figure out how they actually behave in practice and as a result `singleTop` is actually the best for this: no weird animation, app displayed once in the recent applications list (unlike `singleInstance` that displays it twice due to the fact it doesn't allow any other `Activity` to be part of its task), and proper behavious regardless the target `Activity` already exists or not.

Comment: Work until 10pm on Friday night and this is what I want... Sad developer life.

Comment: Saved much of my time! Thank you!

Answer (score 25):

This is old thread, but for all those who is still seeking for answer, here is my solution. It is purely in code, without manifest settings:

```
private static PendingIntent prepareIntent(Context context) {
  Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);      
  return PendingIntent.getActivity(context, NON_ZERO_REQUEST_CODE, intent, 
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
```

Here FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP opens existing activity if it is at the top of task stack. If it is not at the top, but inside stack, FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP will remove all activities on top of target activity and show it. If activity is not in the task stack, new one will be created. A crucially important point to mention - second parameter of PendingIntent.getActivity(), i.e. requestCode should have non-zero value (I even called it NON_ZERO_REQUEST_CODE in my snippet), otherwise those intent flags will not work. I have no idea why it is as it is. Flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP is interchangeable with android:launchMode="singleTop"
in activity tag in manifest.

Comment: Fighting since hours with these flags and was wondering why changing my intent flags didnt change anything. Non-zero request code ... a crucially important point to mention!!! Works now! Thank you!

Comment: Wow! It works! Nice!

Answer (score 11):

I know it is old, but nothing from the above were fitting to my application.

Without changing manifests and other configuration, here is the code to bring your app back to front - or opening it when it is closed

```
Intent notificationIntent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(context.getPackageName());
notificationIntent.setPackage(null); // The golden row !!!
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
```

Comment: This is the real answer!

Comment: no, it is no working - it add a new activity on top of the current one.

Comment: @Tobliug I guess it would have worked for you if you tried removing the flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` ?

Answer (score 3):

I tried this, and it worked even though the IDE was complaining about the code

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(THIS_CONTEXT, MainActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(THIS_CONTEXT, 0, notificationIntent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(THIS_CONTEXT)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.cast_ic_notification_0)
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setContentText("Content")
            .setContentIntent(intent)
            .setPriority(PRIORITY_HIGH) //private static final PRIORITY_HIGH = 5;
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            /*.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS)*/;
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) THIS_CONTEXT.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">

Comment: `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` is not a valid flag for `PendingINtent.getActivity`

Comment: @rds Can you link the source?

Comment: @LouisCAD I am sorry, I do not have access to the source code anymore

Comment: @rds I'm not asking for the source code, but for the link of where you read that `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` is not a valid flag when used as a `PendingIntent`. Or maybe you meant its not valid to pass into the `getActivity` method, but is valid to use as `Intent` flag that is then used as a `PendingIntent`?

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since you say you want to start your activity if it's not started already, maybe you wouldn't mind restarting it. I tested a ton of suggestions and flag combinations for the intent as well, this will always bring the activity you need to the front, though it won't keep any state previously associated with it.

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

API11+ only.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue after adding notifications as found on the [android training site](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification#java). None of the other answers here worked for me, however [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5502950/1684720) did work for me. Summary:

```
final Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, YourActivity.class);
notificationIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
notificationIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Comment: You're stuck down here at the bottom of the answers list but this in the one that worked for me.

`android:launchMode="singleInstance"` documentation says "if it is ever launched again with the same Intent...". Therefore your solution works by recreating the Intent used to initially launch the Activity.

Only difference I had was using the flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`