# Processing firebase data notification's default behaviour

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

While the app is in the background and you're receiving a push notification with both the notification body and the data inside. The push isn't received onMessageReceived. Instead it is sent to the device's system tray where it waits for the user's click. The default behaviour of this click will call the onCreate method of the launcher activity, as if the app is restarting.

[image: User tap open app launcher by default]

Is there anyway to override this behaviour and just open the app normally

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to understand the default firebase background notification exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48291651/trying-to-understand-the-default-firebase-background-notification-exceptions)

Comment: @PeterHaddad I deleted the previous question. This one is more specific

Comment: I found the solution. https://stackoverflow.com/a/23125638/5310148

Comment: U could use pending intent to take the user to a specific activity

Comment: @PeterHaddad I can't build these types of background notifications. They are sent with an intent filter of Launcher by default, or I will need to control that from the payload, which I wanted to avoid