# Android intent bring activity to top or create one case necessary

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Very simple question I'm starting an Activity and I want to be sure there will be exaclty one of that at the stack...

imagine the stacks:

A B C <- top
C <- top

in Activity C i'm starting A, but if A already exists I want it to be brought to the top instead of create a new one...

Which flags shall i pass to the intent?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intent - if activity is running, bring it to front, else start a new one (from notification)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19039189/intent-if-activity-is-running-bring-it-to-front-else-start-a-new-one-from-n)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your Activity A in AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK and FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP.

[image]