# How to open and switch other app using intent

Tags: java, android, flutter, android-intent, build

Before change my computer,

```
Intent intent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.x.y");
    if (intent != null) {
    // We found the activity now start the activity
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString(_key, _data);
        intent.putExtras(b); //Put your id to your next Intent
        context.startActivity(intent);

        return true;
}
```

I could open and switch com.x.y app. It worked well, but a few months ago, I changed my computer and downloaded the latest version of Android Studio.

There are no problems to build, but when I run this code, my Flutter app just opens app com.x.y and not switching. Before changing my computer, it opened and switched to app com.x.y well.

Also, it works well in device using Android 8.1, but not in a device using Android 13.

Comment: use this plugin to open the app https://pub.dev/packages/android_intent_plus

Comment: Have you checked the logcat to see if there are any relevant error mesages that would indicate why it doesn't switch to the other app? Don't filter the logcat or you might miss something important/relevant.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intent - if activity is running, bring it to front, else start a new one (from notification)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19039189/intent-if-activity-is-running-bring-it-to-front-else-start-a-new-one-from-n)