# resume current background activity on notification android

Tags: java, android

I have multiple activities in my application. I want when notification shows in the bar, and clicking on it, it will resume from the activity which is currently in background.

Currently, I am using this, but it will always take me to the Home Activity which is Launcher activity.

```
Intent intent =new Intent(ServiceClass.this, home.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(GcmIntentService.this, 0, intent, 0);
```

Comment: Do mean that you want to start some other activity other than Home Activity or Do you want to resume an existing Home activity screen?

Comment: I want to resume activity from where app has gone into the background. weather it is the home activity or other activity

Comment: Refer this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502427/resume-application-and-stack-from-notification

Answer (score 0):

use the same intent filters as android uses when launches the app:

```
    final Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, YourActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    notificationIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
```

Comment: my main activity is splashActivity, it taken me at this activity, instead of resume from current activity