# android - notification click - if app closed open activity, if app opened bring show current activity

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications, android-pendingintent

I have a service with an ongoing notification. in the app itself I have two activities - `HomeActivity` and `SettingsActivity`.

Currently what I have is -> when the notification is clicked:

1. If the app is closed -> open the `HomeActivity`.
2. If the current showing activity is `HomeActivity`, bring it to front without creating a new one.

**Code:**

```
resultIntent = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);
resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Notification notification = mBuilder
                .setSmallIcon(notificationData.getImageSrc())  // the status icon
                .setTicker("HealthChecker")  // the status text
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())  // the time stamp
                .setContentTitle("HealthChecker")  // the label of the entry
                .setContentText(notificationData.getText())  // the contents of the entry
                .setOngoing(true).setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                .build();
```

**Manifest:** I added `android:launchMode="singleTop":

```
<activity
            android:name=".ui.HomeActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
```

The problem I have is:

when I am in the `SettingsActivity` and I click the notification, it opens a new instance of `HomeActivity`.

What I want is when the **app is opened in either activity** and notification is clicked -> show current activity, and if **app is closed** and notification is clicked, open new instance of `HomeActivity`.

Comment: i think you should read this https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation.html

Comment: I closed this as duplicate. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502427/resume-application-and-stack-from-notification as it covers exactly this problem.

Answer (score 3):

> when I am in the SettingsActivity and I click the notification, it opens a new instance of HomeActivity.

Because this is what `singleTop` is for:

> However, if the target task already has an existing instance of the
>   activity at the top of its stack, that instance will receive the new
>   intent (in an onNewIntent() call); a new instance is not created. In
>   other circumstances — for example, if an existing instance of the
>   "singleTop" activity is in the target task, **but not at the top of
>   the stack**, or if it's at the top of a stack, but not in the target
>   task — a new instance would be created and pushed on the stack.

which is your case because what you have on top is `SettingsActivity`.

> What I want is when the app is opened in either activity and notification is clicked -> show current activity, and if app is closed and notification is clicked, open new instance of HomeActivity

Then your notification should perhaps send intent to 3rd activity (w/o ui) which would then redirect further and `finish()`. Depending on what is your targetSdk you may want to use [ActivityLifecycleCallbacks](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html) to figure out when your app is front most one or not.

Comment: Although this answer will work, it is the very long way around. You end up writing a lot of unecessary code and complicating your app. The problem OP has is very common and there is a very easy way to deal with it. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502427/resume-application-and-stack-from-notification

Comment: @DavidWasser that's should work and if so, it's better solution than mine, but if you follow the comments bellow the accepted answer there then it sounds like not a rock solid solution.

Comment: Yes it does work. All the time. You can safely ignore the few comments from people who say that it doesn't. I think they probably had other problems that were causing them issues.

Comment: @DavidWasser great solution! thanks! works great

Comment: @DavidWasser actually, after further testing, it doesn't work in one scenario: launching the app, (notification not running), activity A is on front, starting the notification, (notification running), going to activity B, clicking the notification opens activity A again.  it works great, but only after starting notification and closing the app (removing from opened app list), it works as excepted afterwords for each scenario.

Comment: anyone knows how to handle this issue?

Comment: @OfekAgmon please post a new question with this problem. Explain exactly what you are doing (post code) and explain what you are seeing. I'm sure that there is a reasonable explanation. This comment thread in this answer in this closed question is not the right place to explore your problem.