# Resume activity from notification calling onCreate

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, notifications

I am trying to resume my activity from a notification, but it is recreating the activity and not resuming.

As all posts regarding this issue, mention creating a `PendingIntent` and setting this with the appropriate flags (as shown in code below), and adding the `singleTop|singleInstance` to the AndroidManifest.

Notification Code:

```
NotificationManager mNotifyMan = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotifyMan.cancelAll();
        Notification.Builder mNB = new Notification.Builder(this);
        mNB.setOngoing(true);
        Intent intent = new Intent(parentContext, main.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(parentContext, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        mNB.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        mNB.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notify_icon);
        mNB.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_noti_large));
        mNB.setContentTitle(Title);
        mNB.setContentText(Message);
        mNB.setColor(0);
        mNotifyMan.notify(777, mNB.build());
```

I understand one must pass an intent with the current context.

When resuming an activity via the `onPause()` on `onResume()`, it resumes and restores the last activity state, i.e. a thread counter running has incremented values.

**Problem:**

When resuming from the notification (i.e. clicking on the notification),  the activity is recreated. I have attempted to resolve this by

when `onPause()` is executed, sending the current activity state via base class to the notification, thus recreating the notification with the current state.

Here is my AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.cynetstudios.wifimanager">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance">

        <activity android:name="com.cynetstudios.frequencyselector.main" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name="com.cynetstudios.frequencyselector.serviceWifiFreqManager" android:exported="false"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I might be missing something trivial, any advice?

Comment: Using `singleInstance` launch mode is not the correct way to deal with this. It will break your app big time if your app has more than 1 `Activity`. You should look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502427/resume-application-and-stack-from-notification/5502950#5502950

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set your Activity's `launchMode` `SingleTask`, `SingleTop` or `SingleInstance` depending on how you want your activity to act.

Later you can handle your activity's onNewIntent method if your activity is open when user clicks your active notification.

Also you need to define activity's launchMode in that atcitvity's part. I edited your xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.cynetstudios.wifimanager">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name="com.cynetstudios.frequencyselector.main"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name="com.cynetstudios.frequencyselector.serviceWifiFreqManager" android:exported="false"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I hope this'll help you.

Answer (score 1):

launchMode should be used in Activity section (not application)

Comment: thanks, the guide I followed showed the launchMode in the application tag, this works, thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
intent.setClass(this, main.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
startActivity(intent);
```

You can try this Intent. Such an intent is used by system app launcher, which will just show(no recreate) your activity if it is not killed.

Comment: This works, but then it doesn't call `onNewIntent`, so I can't put extras into the Intent, that could be used... Any idea how to overcome this?

Comment: I use Rxbus to send extra data. The intent above seems cannot take extras when AMS dealing with ActivityRecord and task history

Answer (score 0):

Try

`Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`

with

`Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`

Set them as flags for the intent

Comment: according to the docs, CLEAR_TOP clears all activities till where this one is, thus bringing it to the top

Comment: That means it will not start a new instance of the activity

Answer (score 0):

Try this it may help you:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

and as @Alexander says put android:launchMode="singleTop" into activity tag