# How to move app from background to foreground

Tags: java, android

Currently after click on notification I run new activity of my app

```
Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                this, 0, notifyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        );
```

and in Notification Builer:

```
 .setContentIntent(intent)
```

But this is always new activity.
I want to get my old activity from backstack after click on notification.
Is it possible ?

Comment: I think that's what you're searching for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502427/resume-application-and-stack-from-notification

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resume application and stack from notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502427/resume-application-and-stack-from-notification)