# Nativescript - How to bring app to foreground when notification is pressed

Tags: nativescript

I'm writing a native Android code to open my app when a notification is pressed. If the app is already opened (whether running in foreground or in background), I want clicking the notification to bring the app to front, without restarting it, so that its state is preserved.

I tried the following code (showing only relevant code):

```
        ///////// Create an activity on tap (intent)
        const Intent = android.content.Intent;
        const PendingIntent = android.app.PendingIntent;
        // Create an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
        const intent = new Intent(context, com.tns.NativeScriptActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);


        const pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

        ///////// Creating a notification 
        var NotificationCompat = android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
        const builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setStyle(
                new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                .bigText("By default, the notification's text content is truncated to fit one line.")
                )
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            // Set the intent that will fire when the user taps the notification
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true);

        ///////// Show the notification
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
```

But that opened the application without preserving its state.

Following recommendations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42002705/3944673), I also tried emulating pressing the app icon from the launcher - so that the app is just brought to the frontground and the Nativescript activity is not recreated.

```
        const packageName = context.getPackageName();
        console.log('Package name: ',packageName);

        const emulateLaunchByAppIconIntent = context.getPackageManager()
            .getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName)
            .setPackage(null)
            .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);

        const pendingIntent_emulated = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, emulateLaunchByAppIconIntent, 0);


        ///////// Creating a notification 
        var NotificationCompat = android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
        const builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setStyle(
                new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                .bigText("By default, the notification's text content is truncated to fit one line.")
                )
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            // Set the intent that will fire when the user taps the notification
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent_emulated)
            .setAutoCancel(true);

        ///////// Show the notification
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
```

This indeed made the app come to front, but didn't preserve its state (even if the app was already in foreground - it reloaded the app).

Then I tried pressing a Nativescript application app icon (manually), when the app has just been sent to the background - and I found that it would restart the app, and not just bring it to the foreground.

My question is - why does a Nativescript application behave like this?
How can I make Android just bring the app to foreground and not re-build a new nativescript activity?

Comment: Did you try removing `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`, keep just `FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED`.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in the question above, actually works - and does bring the app to the foreground without restarting the app, preserving its state.

The reason the app was restarting, even by clicking the Nativescript application app icon (manually) **was related to the development environment.**

1. This happened when I was running the app on a physical device while connected to my Mac running `tns run android --bundle`, or
2. Running the app in an emulator (either by running `tns run android --bundle` or by launching the app directly from the app icon)

Running the app on a physical device that is not connected to the nativescript development environment - showed the real behavior - and the app was brought to the foreground without restarting after clicking the notification.

**More info with code examples:**

I found that **there's no need** to launch the app by simulating an icon press using this code

```
const emulateLaunchByAppIconIntent = context.getPackageManager()
   .getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName)
   .setPackage(null)
   .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);

const pendingIntent_emulated = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, emulateLaunchByAppIconIntent, 0);
```

as `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` or `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED` in the code below, is sufficient to bring app to the foreground without restarting after clicking the notification:

```
const openActivityIntent = new Intent(context, com.tns.NativeScriptActivity.class);
openActivityIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
const openActivityPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, openActivityIntent, 0);

///////// Creating a notification
const notificationManager = <NotificationManager> context.getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
var NotificationCompat = android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;

const builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
    .setSound(soundUri)
    .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_lock_idle_alarm)
    .setContentTitle(title)
    .setContentText(message)
    .setStyle(
        new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
        .bigText('More explaination text if needed. Disabled for now.')
        )
    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
    // Set the intent that will fire when the user taps the notification
    .setContentIntent(openActivityPendingIntent)
    .setWhen(scheduledTime)
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .build();


///////// Show the notification
notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder);
```

Hope this helps you if you got into the same issue.